# LDAP: how to organize tree for webapp access?

Tags: linux, authentication

I've the requirements to create a not-so-little webapp where we have only 3 profiles

- admin
- r/w users
- r/o users

We are required to log users in using LDAP tree. I am creating for the first time an OpenLDAP server on Debian an so I'm a lot confused about organization of tree

I understand that LDAP has an admin user that is the sysadmin of the LDAP itself.

I need to add some users in these 3 'groups'

- admin, r/w and r/o

And i need to create an user that cannot access to the app but is valid as ldap user because the organization is large and only some of them can access to ldap. So i need to test what happen when a non-webapp user try to login.

The webapp part is a totally other question and I'm not asking about client part.

I ask you how to organize some others into groups like this

- nonwebapp

  - nonwebappuser1
  - nonwebappuser2
- webapp

  - webappadmins

    - webappadmin1
    - webappadmin2
  - webapprw

    - webapprw1
    - webapprv2
  - webappro

    - webappro1
    - webappro2

I know that `nonwebapp` and `webapp` can be Organizationl Units.

But what about 'role' groups, like webappadmins, webapprw and webappro ?

### This is the main question

How should I organize LDAP tree to allow only a subset of users to access to a webapp and giving them a role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I understand that LDAP has an admin user that is the sysadmin of the LDAP itself.

A *fresh* OpenLDAP installation will have one "root" account, but you can define access control lists afterwards via `olcAccess` (see "man slapd.access").

For example, you can give modify access to members of a specific groupOfNames, give your webapp the ability to update just the "member" attribute, and so on.

In fact you'll probably *need* to define some basic ACLs, in order to prevent non-admin users from seeing what everyone has in their "userPassword" attributes. (And create service accounts to avoid putting the rootDN in all your apps!)

> I know that nonwebapp and webapp can be Organizationl Units.

Once you have roles implemented, the separation into "webapp" and "nonwebapp" becomes purely organizational and is no longer useful for authorization. Since you have to check roles anyway, you just deny access to users who aren't in any role and that's it.

In other words, the directory tree is not the authorization mechanism.

> But what about 'role' groups, like webappadmins, webapprw and webappro ?

There are several ways to implement roles:

- Dedicated "group" entries which list the DNs of every user which is part of that role. There are two common object classes (both pre-defined in core.schema) which would work here:

  - `groupOfNames` is the one typically used for access control. It doesn't allow empty member lists (i.e. the 'member' attribute is required).

    ```
    dn: cn=Read-only users,ou=Webapp roles,o=Widgets Ltd
    objectClass: groupOfNames
    member: uid=webappro1,ou=Webapp users,o=Widgets Ltd
    member: uid=webappro2,ou=Webapp users,o=Widgets Ltd
    ```
  - `organizationalRole` is more meant for "informational" directory entries (like phone book) but there's nothing to stop you from using it for access control as well. It allows empty member lists (roleOccupant is optional).

    ```
    dn: cn=Read/write users,ou=Webapp roles,o=Widgets Ltd
    objectClass: organizationalRole
    roleOccupant: uid=webapprw1,ou=Webapp users,o=Widgets Ltd
    roleOccupant: uid=webapprw2,ou=Webapp users,o=Widgets Ltd
    ```

  Note: Instead of directly checking the group member list, it is best to use the LDAP "Compare" operation as it will recognize that you're dealing with a "DN"-typed attribute, and will take care of DN canonicalization for you.

  (When dealing with direct access to the LDAP database, the OpenLDAP ACL system can support both formats. The `by group=` subject specification will expect groupOfNames by default, but saying `by group/organizationalRole/roleOccupant=` is also possible.)
- Attributes on the account entry itself. You can define a custom attribute and add it into the OpenLDAP schema, or repurpose something existing like `authorizedService`. (This particular attribute is originally used for OS-level authorization, but it doesn't limit what service names you put in there.)

  ```
  dn: uid=webapprw1,ou=Webapp users,o=Widgets Ltd
  objectClass: person
  objectClass: authorizedServiceObject
  authorizedService: webapp/read-only
  ```

  (Note that OpenLDAP's ACLs do not support checking the subject's attributes; in that case you'll still need to use groups.)
- If each user is in exactly *one* role, you could actually use nested OUs just like in your diagram. But checking or changing which OU someone is in needs a bit more code than doing the same via attributes, so I wouldn't use that approach.
- Not making those decisions via LDAP in the first place. It's actually common for applications to *authenticate* users against LDAP (and retrieve info from there), but *authorize* them against some non-LDAP database which is completely internal to the app itself. For example, you could just have a SQL table called 'role_assignments'.

Comment: We will authenticate via LDAP, but our customer has force policy (internals) to profile users using ou of LDAP. Strange system, but it works. 
At webapp side we read ou and use this as role.
No profile page, no user crud, etc... 
PS: thanks for your detailed reply